# JavaEE 8, Tomcat 8.5, Error Status 404

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I'm trying to make my first servlet, but I get a 404 status code.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
     version="4.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Test.Hello</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Hello.java

```
 package Test;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;


public class Hello extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException, ServletException{
        PrintWriter pw = res.getWriter();
        pw.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

I want run it:
localhost:8080/hello

And now its status 404

> "Description The origin server did not find a current representation
>   for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one
>   exists."

How can I fix this?

Comment: try restarting your server

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte didnt work ;/

Comment: Are you using a framework such as spring? Are you compiling the project with maven? Do you have a *.war that has been deployed to you tomcat server? We need more info to be able to help you.

Comment: I'm new, I'm just learning, I don't use maven and frameworks, where can i check if i have *war ? I'm using IntelliJ ? Build -> build artifacts -> build Project:war ?

Comment: how are you deploying this?  where are you editing the web.xml?

Comment: Web -> WEB-INF -> web.xml

Comment: You'll need to add the webapp (web application) name in the URL. In Tomcat this is either the name of your `.war`. file (i.e. `myapp.war` would use `http://localhost:8080/myapp/hello`) or the name of the directory you created under the Tomcat `webapps` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very strange, i noticed that your web.xml is in version 4.0.. You should be able to use url mapping with your Servlet through annotations.

Try adding a WebServlet annotation `@WebServlet("/hello")` like this:

```
 package Test;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet; //IMPORT THIS ALSO
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

@WebServlet("/hello") //try adding this here
public class Hello extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException, ServletException{
        PrintWriter pw = res.getWriter();
        pw.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

And then remove any mapping you have in web.xml, which is not needed if you are using annotations.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
     version="4.0">

//remove servlet and mapping    

</web-app>
```

If that doesn't work another thing you can try is change your version. For example, replace your web.xml with this (which is version 3.1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">

</web-app>
```